# ValueError when decompressing several results after parallelization

Tags: python, geopandas, valueerror

when I try to unpack my results after having closed my multiprocessing.pool, I get this :

```
def worker_1(x, y, z):
    ...
    t = zip(list_of_Polygon,list_of_Polygon,list_of_Point,column_Point)
return t

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 146, in <module>
    a,b,c,d = t
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

another way to save several output geodataframe or geoseries variables??

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def worker_1(x, y, z):
    t = list(zip(list_of_Polygon,list_of_Polygon,list_of_Point,column_Point))
    return t
```

OR

```
def worker_1(x, y, z):
    t = list_of_Polygon,list_of_Polygon,list_of_Point,column_Point
    return t
```

Comment: That not work u,u

Comment: Create a minimal sample of your data if you want to get help.